# Searching for images inside source

Tags: c#, image

I have many .png files, which are flags of many countries. Each .png file is named after its country. I want to load them all to my program (as Images or Bitmaps) to draw them in ComboBox (country selection). But I dont want to make additional folder for flags - all included in exe. How to do this? I have added them to my project, but how to scan internal source folder for flags?

//Sry for strange title, but "Quality standards" filter is blocking everything

Answer (score 0):

Change the "Build action" for each file to "Resource" and change "Copy file" to "Never", then reference them as follows:

XAML:

```
<Image Name="flag" Source="/ProjectName;component/Resources/path/to/file/argentina.png" Width="16" Height="16" />
```

Code:

```
var img = new BitmapImage();
img.BeginInit();
img.UriSource = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/ProjectName;component/Resources/path/to/file/argentina.png");
img.EndInit();
flag.Source = img;
```

Comment: Well, it wont work for me. I have many files, but dont have they names. So i need to search for files in directory (like "dir" in windows batch).